# ASP.NET HeadLoginView Logout Click. Logs out of other local websites too

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication

I have 2-3 web projects ( beginner ones). In all the websites I have a login control where a user can log in. When the user logins with correct info, I set the

```
 protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{

    if (CHUser.AunthencateLogin(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password))//Checks with database
        e.Authenticated = true;
    else
        e.Authenticated = false;
 }
```

Up to here is fine, but the problem occurs when I login into 2 separate websites (local) at same time, and log out at any one of them. When I log out at one the other website is also logged out ( when refreshed). Following is the code I use when logging out.

```
protected void LoginStatus1_LoggingOut(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Clear(); //though logout works without this code. It is for other
 //sessions that are manually created by me
        }
```

I can't see to find out what's the cause of it. I am also new to web development.

I would also like to know if this is the right way of logging in a user.

Comment: Similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454623/multiple-applications-using-same-login-database-logging-each-other-out/2491686#2491686

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answered in a question edit. converted to a community wiki answer. See [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) )

The OP wrote:

> Thanks @Aristos. the problem was solved by using the following code on web.config 1st project
>
> ```
> <authentication mode="Forms">
>  <forms name=".Cookie1" ... />
> </authentication>
> ```
>
> 2nd project
>
> ```
> <authentication mode="Forms">
>      <forms name=".Cookie2" ... />
>     </authentication>
> ```