# Multiple applications with membership and same applicationName

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, web-config, asp.net-membership

My problem is the same that:
[Multiple applications using same login database logging each other out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454623/multiple-applications-using-same-login-database-logging-each-other-out)

> I've set up two ASP.NET applications on a machine, their web.config
>   files contain the same applicationName value in
>   AspNetSqlMembershipProvider item so they share users and roles.
>
> The problem sequence is:
>
> user logs into application A, opens new tab in a browser logs into
>   application B, his login in application A is signed out and vice
>   versa.
>
> Should I use a different approach to sharing login information between
>   two applications?

The problem is that the solution, only avoid signed out beetween applications, but the applications do not share users logins.
I want that.

- User logs into application A
- He opens new tab and goes to application B --> User is logged into application B because he was logged in A.
- And vice versa

How can i make this?

Comment: Have a look at the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454623/multiple-applications-using-same-login-database-logging-each-other-out

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you follow these instructions:
http://telligent.com/support/telligent_evolution_platform/w/documentation/common-things-to-check-when-using-forms-authentication.aspx

Keep cookiename, domain and machine key the same. This worked for me, but my app is in a subdirectory of the other app.

Comment: But if I keep cookiename the same, "when user logs into application A, opens new tab in a browser logs into application B, his login in application A is signed out and vice versa."

Comment: But it's the same login and id? And the same account?

Comment: @Pedre The problem is the same cookiename and not the same login/password and membership.

Comment: But he needs the same cookie in order to automatically login to the other app. No?

Comment: @Remy exact, I need that automatically login to the other app. I mean, I login in application A with user X, i need that if i go to application B URL I am already logged as user X. But if I keep cookiename the same, "when user logs into application A, opens new tab in a browser logs into application B, his login in application A is signed out and vice versa."