# logout without any reason in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I make a website with asp.net and it works fine. but sometimes it kick users out of their account with out any reason. I mention in my web config for session and web form time out. but it happen again.
and also my data for the sessions are not too much.for example a word!(journal x).
can any body help me?... I become confused! 
here is my web config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=session;timeout=5;" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />


    <handlers>
      <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
      <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST"
        path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.net>

    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="waag@waag.ir">
        <network host="mail.waag.ir" port="25" userName="*****" password="*****"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
  <connectionStrings>

    <!--<add name="dbconn" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
        <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>-->


    <add name="dbconn" connectionString="Password=****;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=****;Initial Catalog=esfahanhost_****;Data Source=174.142.4.132" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

    <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>

    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Password=****;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=****;Initial Catalog=esfahanhost_****;Data Source=174.142.4.132" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />


  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>





    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">

      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="dbconn"
           enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
           maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
           applicationName="/" />

      </providers>
    </membership>


    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30"/>
    <roleManager enabled="true"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">  
      <forms timeout="30" slidingExpiration="true" name="AC7.ASPXAUTH" />
    </authentication>

      <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>

          <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
          <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
          <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        </assemblies>
      </compilation>
      <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never" enableViewStateMac="false">
          <controls>
              <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting"
                  assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
          </controls>

      </pages>

  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Does your app throw out all sessions at the same time or just individual sessions, while other sessions remain active?

Comment: each session throw out individually.

Comment: Can you see any events raised in the Event Viewer on your server regarding an invalid ticket?

Answer (score 0):

The login information's are stored on one cookie, and if you do not have setup the domain on the web.config for the cookie and you move from eg `www.domain.com` to `domain.com` the cookie is not working and may log out.

So set the `domain` on your form tag as (do not place the www):

```
<authentication mode="Forms">  
  <forms domain="yoursitename.com" timeout="30" slidingExpiration="true" name="AC7.ASPXAUTH" />
</authentication>
```

also set the **domain** on the `roleManager` tag and on cookie tag.

More to read about:
[Can some hacker steal the cookie from a user and login with that name on a web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498599/can-some-hacker-steal-the-cookie-from-a-user-and-login-with-that-name-on-a-web-s)
[Multiple applications using same login database logging each other out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454623/multiple-applications-using-same-login-database-logging-each-other-out/2491686#2491686)

Comment: should i do this for sessions too?

Comment: thank you so much for your great answer.my final question is, dose the domain="yoursitename.com" need "www" or "http://" ?

Comment: @SaeedTalaee You DO NOT set the http:// - and you do NOT place the `www` ether ! This is point of use it, to set the same cookie ether with www, or with out them - or else the cookie is different.

Comment: a problem occur!!! I can not log in any more! as i log in, nothing happen, and log in page appear again.

Comment: <forms domain="waag.ir" timeout="30" slidingExpiration="true" name="AC7.ASPXAUTH" />

Comment: of course...
role author for any journal
Username:author@waag.ir
Password :123456

Comment: @SaeedTalaee Its seems that you do not have setup correct the urls/rewrite/redirect or something similar because the `http://www.aag.ir/Author/S0_Start.aspx` is not working after login and change the `www` Do you make any redirect ? Also nether this works : `https://www.waag.ir/Login.aspx` - you have some error on https pages

Comment: yes i make redirects there!
should i omit them. if i omit them the how redirect users to their pages?

Comment: and one more thing i never checked my site in https// before!
why this error happen?!