# Asp.net site lost authentication when login in other site on same server

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, authentication, forms-authentication

I have 2 Asp.net website in the same ISS7 webserver.
Both site use forms authentication.
When I'm logged in on first web site and I try to login on second web site, I lost authentication on fisrt one.
I need use both site on same browser and now is impossible.

What can I do to solve my problem?

**SOLVED**

I found solution in this post
[Multiple applications using same login database logging each other out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454623/multiple-applications-using-same-login-database-logging-each-other-out)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple applications using same login database logging each other out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454623/multiple-applications-using-same-login-database-logging-each-other-out)

Comment: Please check the answer I have given in above link, I believe you have the same issue, and you can solve it with changing the cookie name on authentication on web.config.

Comment: I found Solution here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454623/multiple-applications-using-same-login-database-logging-each-other-out

Comment: This is the link I give you (and my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that both web applications are using the same machineKey values in the web.configs.  This is used for encryption/decryption of the forms authentication ticket.  There is really good information here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I login in each site with two different credentials and I need two different token.

Comment: Sorry - I made an assumption!  The comment above from Aristos is correct.

Comment: I tryed to put following code in both my web.config, but don't work.
When I update page on second site, I lost authentication on first one.
`<machineKey validationKey="C50B3C89CB21F4F1422FF158A5B42D0E8DB8CB5CDA1742572A487D9401E3400267682B202B746511891C1BAF47F8D25C07F6C39A104696DB51F17C529AD3CABE" decryptionKey="8A9BE8FD67AF6979E7D20198CFEA50DD3D3799C77AF2B72F" 
          validation="SHA1" />`