# "The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context" upon server deploy (MVC5 / IIS 7.5)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am deploying an MVC 5 web app created in VS2015 MVC template. The app works great inside VS2015 However after publish (to file system then copy) to a Windows 2008 R2 Server / IIS 7.5 - Pointing the browser to the app root gives the above error. Pointing to /Account/Login gives a slightly different:

```
"The name 'model' does not exist in the current context"
```

I've read many answers regards this error but none helped and none were specific to my env versions. Ive already tried:

- Deploying to a virtual directory
- Deploying to a root level blank website
- Adding
- Verifying App pool is .Net 4 / Integrated
- Adding a web.config to the views folder (MVC 5 don't create by default)

What am I missing?

The error I get (after allowing detailed errors in web.config):

My Error:

```
Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context

Source Error:


Line 1:  @{
Line 2:      ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
Line 3:  }
Line 4:
```

My web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=win10nh\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=*****;uid=sa;password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /><add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=win10nh\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=*****;uid=sa;password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="*****Entities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.EFmodel.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.EFmodel.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.EFmodel.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=win10nh\sqlexpress;initial catalog=*****;user id=sa;password=*****;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /><add name="*****Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.EFmodel.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.EFmodel.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.EFmodel.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=win10dev\sqlexpress;initial catalog=*****;user id=sa;password=*****;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>

  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <!--http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454623/multiple-applications-using-same-login-database-logging-each-other-out-->
    <!--<forms timeout="20" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" domain="gc.*****.com" />-->
    <forms timeout="60" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" />
  </authentication>

  <membership>
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" applicationName="/" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" />
    </providers>
  </membership>    

  <roleManager enabled="true">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
  </roleManager>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <!--<add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="sqlServerMembership" />-->
      </providers>
      <properties>
        <!--add name="UiCulture" serializeAs="String" allowAnonymous="true" />-->
      </properties>
    </profile>


    <!--<authentication mode="Forms" />-->
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>

  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <!--<remove name="FormsAuthentication" />-->
      <!--<add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />-->
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `pages` tag to `system.web` tag in config file.

```
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.5">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Also check the web.config file of the `Views` folder

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Net.Http" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>

    <!--
        Enabling request validation in view pages would cause validation to occur
        after the input has already been processed by the controller. By default
        MVC performs request validation before a controller processes the input.
        To change this behavior apply the ValidateInputAttribute to a
        controller or action.
    -->
    <pages
        validateRequest="false"
        pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Nkosi, Thanks for you answer.
- Adding "pages" tag in root web.config - no change.
- Adding a your suggested web.config to the Views folder - New error below:

Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Source Error:


Line 26:     using System.Web.Optimization;
Line 27:     using System.Web.Routing;
Line 28:     using System.Net.Http;
Line 29:     
Line 30:

Comment: @user3104076, I said add `pages` to `system.web` tag, not the root. Anyhow looks like you have bigger issues on your hands. Try creating a new project from scratch and compare its configuration with what you have in your project that is not working. Should give you a clue as to what may be causing your issue.