# In windows authentication how to allow the users if subdomain(abc) is used in URL like http://abc.localhost/myweb/

Tags: c#, asp.net

In windows authentication without subdomain `http://localhost/myweb/` its asking username/password after successful its displaying application page.

But when I ran with subdomain `http://abc.localhost/myweb/`
its not taking the login credentials, Its giving Unauthorized access error.
what changes I need to do to overcome this problem.

what I tried is:
in `Web.config` I changed allow users to `*` and deny users to `?` but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Its because the cookie is change and depended on the subdomain and domain - to make it keep the same cookie you have to define the `domain` parameter on the authentication lines and on cookie on `web.config`

The lines that you have to define it are...

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms domain="domain.com"  .... />
</authentication>
<roleManager domain="domain.com" >
     .... other lines .....
</roleManager>
<httpCookies domain="domain.com" .... />
```

Setting up the correct domain with out subdomain you can have the same authenticated cookie on your subdomains

Other similar questions : [Multiple applications using same login database logging each other out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454623/multiple-applications-using-same-login-database-logging-each-other-out/2491686#2491686)