# LogOut in asp.net webforms

Tags: asp.net, session, webforms, runtime-error, logout

I have a web forms application that I tested and works good locally. When i upload it to a web server that hosts my site, it often just logs out users.

More than a month now, this problem is created - without reason users get out of the system and must log in again.

Sometimes get out again after a minute - sometimes after a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

### authentication cookie

The loggin issues are connected with the cookies that you set. Usually a move from `www.` to `non www.` can make the cookie lost if domain is not set,
or a move from secure `https` to  non secure `http` and vice versa.

Make sure that you have set the `domain` (with out the `www.`) on this sections on `web.config` as:

```
<httpCookies domain="domain.com"  />
<roleManager domain="domain.com"  />
<forms domain="domain.com" requireSSL="true" />
```

### session cookie

One other issue may be **a connection of the session with the login**, and **if its lose the session is also lost the login**.

In this case you must check the expire  and recycle of the session. If its in memory consider to move it on database.

### secure your login

Also consider this question [Can some hacker steal a web browser cookie from a user and login with that name on a web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498599/can-some-hacker-steal-a-web-browser-cookie-from-a-user-and-login-with-that-name) for more settings on the cookies.

### other links

Related answer [Multiple applications using same login database logging each other out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454623/multiple-applications-using-same-login-database-logging-each-other-out/2491686#2491686)