# Zoom Web SDK integration issue in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, zoom-sdk, conference

I am working on video conference with Zoom Web SDK 1.9 in asp.net(C#) web application, and it is working as expected.
But as soon as I join the zoom meeting and try to refresh the page or navigate to other page via menu, it is automatically logged out from the web application and redirect to login page. Without joining zoom meeting all pages of web application are working fine, with no logout issue.

Now I have to re-login into the web application to visit other page. If any one having any idea on how to overcome with this problem please suggest.

Comment: this is usual a cookie problem

Comment: How to overcome with this problem, I am clueless.

Comment: take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68345475/logout-in-asp-net-webforms/68345677#68345677

Comment: and on this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454623/multiple-applications-using-same-login-database-logging-each-other-out/2491686#2491686